# yii2 server responding very slowly

Tags: php, yii2

Here is my ation in my profile controller

```
public function actionFavourites($id) {   
    $owner_id = My::currentUserId();

    $favs = (new Query())
        ->select('*')
        ->from('user_favs')
        ->where(['anmt_id' => $id, 'owner_id' => $owner_id])
        ->one();

    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        // if user is a guest
        $alert = 'E\'lonni saralanganlarga qo\'shish uchun iltimos, profilingizga kiring!';
        return $alert;
        exit(); 
    } else {
        // if user is not a guest
        // Removing from favorites
        if ($favs) {
            Yii::$app->db
                ->createCommand()
                ->delete('user_favs', ['anmt_id' => $id, 'owner_id' => $owner_id])
                ->execute();

            return 'removed';               
        } else {
            // Adding to favorites
            Yii::$app->db
                ->createCommand()
                ->insert('user_favs', ['anmt_id' => $id, 'owner_id' => $owner_id])
                ->execute();

            return 'added';
        }
    }
}
```

`$owner_id` is the id of the owner of "favourite announcement" and `$id` is the id of announcement.

When I go to http://optombor.uz/profile/favourites?id=2 it insert the anouncement into the user_favs and then refreshed but it didn't delete the announcement from the table but after 20 seconds when I refresh it deleted. Then I refreshed to insert again but it didn't I had to wait for 20 seconds again.

What is the problem?

Comment: 20 seconds waiting or page loaded compllely after 20 seconds you refresh again ?

Comment: No, the page refreshing immediately but adding and removing being done after 20 seconds

Comment: without any  excuting  the page after that ?

Comment: maybe some one else refresh the page

Comment: for example when I go to http://optombor.uz/profile/favourites?id=2 actionFavourites returned 'added' and refreshing again still returns 'added' refreshing for 20 seconds returning only 'added' only after 20 seconds it returns removed

Comment: E'lonni saralanganlarga qo'shish uchun iltimos, profilingizga kiring! , please enable it without  loging

Comment: Still the same without logging

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162204/discussion-between-kiamoz-and-gofur-n).

Comment: it's not a good way to work with DBs in yii2 ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after checking your codes via random numbers , that wont be change . and it's a cache on your hosting server .

Comment: Hey bro I just noticed that my page not refreshing

Comment: I changed my action like this

Comment: I send the change to chat